# Why am i not able to login successfully in asp.net web application when using jmeter?

Tags: asp.net, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have to record a load test for a successful login and further browsing in to the asp.net application.

After recording the script in jmeter, my samplers are 1) get request (login page) 2) post request (posting the credentials and click login) 3)and other samplers (after successful login).

My problem is it shows incorrect username password error(manually it is working) whenever i play the the script, i have parameterized the valid credentials, also did correlation(by seeing the post request i got to know the fields that were posted) with event state validation, viewstate genearator, viewstate and hdnkey from get response(sampler 1) to my post request(sampler 2) and tried again, but i am getting the same error everytime.

Please let me know, what should be done to login successfully. So i can perform the load test on this asp.net application.i have came accross lots of sites for this issue but nothing solved it. Please help!

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Thanks. will provide an clear example of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to debug your JMeter script. Look [here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/step-step-debugger-jmeter-it%E2%80%99s-not-dream-anymore) and [here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script). I would use [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) as the first step for seeing variables values.

You can use tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to record the requests that are made when you manually login into the site. Then you can compare them with your JMeter script.

Comment: Hi, i added debug sampler in my script and it was very helpful to debug the jmeter properties and variables. But to make my script work, i have to send encrypted password through jmeter in the post request.please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Make sure to correlate any dynamic parameters like [View State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx), [EventValidation](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/04/23/asp-net-2-0-event-validation.html), etc.
3. Run your test with 1 virtual user and 1 loop and inspect request and response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. Compare requests you send with JMeter with what real browser sends (can be found in your browser [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) "Network" tab") - requests should be the same (apart from dynamic parameters)

Check out [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article for example test plan building explained.

Comment: Hi dmitri, I followed your steps and it is working but they are sending encrypted password in the login page which has been created using reverse encryption method, bcoz of this jmeter shows invalid username /password.I have copied the viewstate, event validation and encrypted pwd from developers tools request(manual request to the .net application) and passed it through jmeter it is working, but please help me to continue this process through jmeter(to send encrypted password through jmeter)